# Dropdown Menu ul li jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Ive been trying to make a Drop Down menu with ul li and Jquery as in this [Tutorial](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index3.html)

Here's the test HTML Code:

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
<span>OS</span>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="http://www.ubuntu.com/"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>Ubuntu</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>Microsoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/ch/"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Apple</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to have if you click on "Apple" it redirects to the Apple Site and same with Microsoft redirects to Microsoft and so on. But at the moment if you click any of these it always redirects you to the ubuntu website.

Here's the whole code with the Javascript on [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Barret/xyUP3/).

Thx for any help.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: SO should add an kind of option when you try to submit a question to show a popup to invite user to post relevant code. Oh, wait...

Comment: Yeah, i'm having a hard time understanding the question. Post the HTML and JS code so we can see what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Barret, it's necessary to edit and post your code so that I can see what's the problem.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. I've edited my Question above and hope it's more clear to understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is a little confussing but what I can gather is that you're li elements are linking to the same page?

Since li are not default hyperlinks I'm guessing that you're using JS/JQuery to achieve this. In the tutorial you linked they are using nav and anchors.

Here is an exmaple of a working li menu system that might suit you're needs.

```
      $(function(){ // Wait till page is loaded

        $(".menulink").click(function(){ // do something on click of one of the menu items.
            window.location.replace($(this).data("link")); //get the data link and redirect to it
        });

    });
```

Here is the HTML list you could use. The data attribute is used to store the URL

```
    <ul>
    <li class="menulink" data-link="www.example.com">Menu1</li>
    <li class="menulink" data-link="www.example.com">Menu2</li>
    <li class="menulink" data-link="www.example.com">Menu3</li>
    </ul>
```

**Update:**

After taking a look at your fiddle I was able to get it working

http://jsfiddle.net/xyUP3/14/

I think the issue was simply a type-o. You were referencing "opts" which is the global li object when you should have been referencing "opt" which was the local li instance that was just clicked. Hence you were always getting hyperlinked to the first li on the page which was the ubuntu link

Comment: Thanks for the kind help, though its less of a menu just gonna be a few different dropdowns in the end and it needs the "a href" tag.

Comment: You should also consider using children instead of find, as children only travels a single level down the DOM tree **window.location = opt.children('a').prop('href');**

Comment: @bastos.sergio I tried using children at first when I was debugging the code.:D